# NOW() only saves the date, not time

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query

```
"INSERT INTO front_articles (poster_id, username, title, message, date) 
 VALUES ('$poster_id', '$db_username', '$title', '$text',NOW()";
```

But when I read it off database it only shows 2013-10-05, what do I do for it to show time too?

Answer (score 5):

Your `date` column is of type `date`. You can only save a date in it. Change it to `datetime` to save both.

Answer (score 2):

Change your database table column type `datetime` instead of `date`

Answer (score 1):

[NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) Returns the current date and time as a value in `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` format

So you could modify your date column as `datetime`

and also close the bracket `)` at the end of inputed values

Your query as

```
INSERT INTO front_articles (poster_id, username, title, message, date)
   VALUES ('$poster_id', '$db_username', '$title', '$text',NOW());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert always `NOW()` and not sth. like "2013-10-04 13:22:00" you can use the column type `timestamp`.